# Building and distributing an iOS SDK with dependencies that can be easily integrated in objective-c and swift apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk, cocoapods

I'm working on building and distributing an iOS SDK that has few dependencies (i.e. AFNetworking, ProtocolBuffers, GZIP, CocoaAsyncSocket etc..). The distribution of the compiled SDK is done using cocoapods which allows to install those dependencies as expected.

The problem I'm having right now is that I would like to support both objective-c as well as swift apps which means that ideally I should support two flavors of the SDK: static and dynamic.

Unfortunately, cocoapods doesn’t seem to easily support building and distributing different flavors of a framework and based on my understanding, if I was going to keep using cocoapods, I would probably need to have different Podfiles, workspaces etc.. which is not ideal.

That being said, I was curious to  know if anyone here had similar problem and how was solved. The goal is to distribute an SDK that has dependencies on other libraries and that can be easily integrated into an objective-c as well as swift app.